# Calling database update in IDisposable.Dispose()

Tags: c#

I want to track life cycle of instances of a class (say `Class1`) in a distributed environment. For ex. there is one SQL Server machine and there are multiple IIS Servers connecting to that SQL Server machine. Multiple instances of an ASP.NET application are hosted on IIS machines (one instance on one machine).

With each request to any instance of the application on any of IIS Servers, an instance of `Class1` is created and the creation time is logged into database. I want to know when that instance of `Class1` is destroyed.

So is it wise to make `Class1` implement `IDisposable` and log the destruction time into database in `Dispose()` method? Considering the fact that update a table with millions of records is potentially time consuming and this forces the Garbage Collector to wait while disposing that instance of object, I am not sure what to do.

The general question is:

Is it wise to call a time consuming operation in `IDisposable.Dispose()` of an object when performance is important?

Please help me with this issue,

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you dispatch the time/object info to a Queue during the Dispose() call. Then you can have a separate thread/process drain that queue to the database. Would be much more efficient, and won't mess with the garbage collection speed.

Comment: @Matt, You are right!, good idea (asynchronous call to update database on an other thread), Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it something that you need to log, you could do it. It is hard to say how it will impact performance without knowing specifics.

However, this will not tell you when the object is destroyed. It will only tell you when the Dispose method is called. The garbage collector may not collect it at that instant. You could give Class1 a finalizer method (i.e. implement the System.Object's Finalize method) and write the log then, but even then, the object wont be destroyed at that point since the garbage collector will evoke the finalizer and destroy the object on a subsequent pass. This will add even more overhead.

Since you cannot get the exact point of destruction, and you seem to only need the Dispose method for this log by the sounds of it, you could just forego using IDisposable. You could just have a method called something like Close() or Finish() which you call when the object is no longer needed or just before it falls out of scope. If Class1 does implement IDisposable, you can use it in a using block if you need to and not have to worry about explicitly calling the Dispose method.

Comment: Thanks for your attention